# Jaynes 3.9 : "Markovian Approximation"

Tags: probability-theory

In the book "Probability : The Logic of Science" what is Jaynes referring to here:[image]

Anyone read Jaynes?

Answer (score 1):

For context for future readers, in Ref. 1., Part I, Ch. 3 "Elementary sampling theory", that snippet of text occurs at the end of Section 3.9 "Correction for correlations".

As per the "common technical language" for the physical problem, an [autoregressive model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model) is a representation of a time-varying stochastic process where the next variable in time depends linearly on its own $p$ previous values and some source of white noise. The "first-order" in this case means it depends only on the previous value, where $p=1$. They call it the "'baby' version" because the first-order only deals with one previous value to affect the next variable.

The autoregressive model is a key component, along with the [moving-average model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model), for the more general [autoregressive-moving-averge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model) (ARMA) and [autoregressive integrated moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) (ARIMA) time series models. These are commonly used time-series models for understanding time-series data or forecasting or predicting future states in time.

There are more general models that rely on the autoregressive model as well, such as the [Autoregressive Conditional Heteroscedastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity) (ARCH) for modeling error variance in a time series. Related to ARCH is the generalized version GARCH when assuming ARMA instead of AR, the nonlinear asymmetric version NAGARCH, among other variants.

A non-exhaustive list of things that invovle autoregressive models:

- Physics models where the state-space is partially measured or known:

  - some weather forecasting of tides or seasonal temperature variations
  - [Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion) can be modeled by an ARMA model as long as the error distribution is correct.
- Quantitative finance models (Ref. 2)
- Models of the spread of epidemics or pandemics

---

### References

1. Jaynes, Edwin Thomas. Editor Bretthorst, G. Larry. "Probability Theory: The Logic of Science" Cambridge University Press. April 10, 2003. ISBN 978-0-511-06589-7.

   - https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511790423
2. Dixon, Matthew F. et al. "Machine Learning in Finance: From Theory to Practice" Springer International Publishing. 2020. ISBN 978-3-030-41068-1. DOI 10.1007/978-3-030-41068-1.

   - http://link.springer.com/10.1007/978-3-030-41068-1

Comment: if you could expound more on what the 'irreversible process' and 'markovian approximation' is?